# Intuition for uncountable intersection being $\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider $A=(0,1)$ and $\forall x\in A$, $E_x=(0,x)$. Consider the set $B=\cap_{x\in A}E_x$. I am trying to build an intuition around why $B=\emptyset$ (and, in general, about uncountable infinity).

Off course, one could argue that for some fixed $b$ from $(0,1)$, we can always find an $x\lt b$, so that $b\notin E_x$.

But from a bird's eye, it's just so counter intuitive to say that $B$ is empty. Should I just accept that and form my intuition around it? :)

Comment: The issue is not with *uncountable* : the intersection of two sets is the "common part", i.e. the subset of those elements that belong to both sets. Thus, the "family" $E_x$ "shrincks" as long as $x$ is becoming more and more "near" to $0$. Thus, the intersection of the collection of all them must contains the "common part", whcih is empty, because the intervals are *open*, i.e. $0$ in not included.

Comment: You are talking about intersections and not unions, so the title is misleading. Also, this is not an uncountable phenomenon. In your notation we also have $B = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}E_{1/n} = \varnothing$, which is a countable intersection.

Comment: @user218931 intersections indeed. And thanks.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks. The intuition fails not because of the interval being open, but because I feel there should be something left all the time. See Mees de Vries's answer.

Comment: The issue does not change : assume that $B$ is not empty; this means that there is an $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon \in E_x$ for **all** $x$. And thus, for how "little" $\epsilon$ is, you can always find e *real* $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta < \epsilon$, and thus $\epsilon \notin E_{\delta}$. It's all. From a math point of view, the fact that we have proved it is enough. My comment above was aimed at helping you to "intuite" why this is so :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note: this an intersection, not a union.

Your argument is correct. However, note that this does not have too much to do with the intersection being uncountable; if you define
$$
E_n = (0,\tfrac 1n),
$$
then
$$
\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty E_i = \emptyset
$$
for basically the same reason. Maybe the problem with your intuition comes from the fact that you feel like there should be something left "at the left" of $(0,1)$ after the full intersection, since each $E_n$ "leaves something to the left" of $(0,1)$. In that case, yes: this is a good opportunity to hone your intuition. What happens "at infinity" is often different from what happens "as you get closer to infinity".

Comment: Great, thank you. Philosophically speaking, isn't the "infinity behaviour" some kind of axiom that we implicitly accept? Nobody's actually "been there" to be sure.

Comment: @hyperio We do declare that $\infty$ exists, yes.  But be careful with saying "nobody's actually been there to be sure."  Math doesn't care about what people see or don't see.  Nor does it care about what people experience or don't experience.  I may have never had infinitely many dollar bills, but that doesn't matter for math.  Math is a conceptual subject, and the concept of $\infty$ is perfectly valid.  As long as you can clearly define something, it is a valid mathematical object.  So try to think less about math as something which we build only from our everyday experience.

Comment: @user46944 great, thank you!

Comment: @hyperio, There is nothing really implicit/implicitly accepted about what we are doing here. We have simply defined some set, namely $\cap_{i=1}^\infty E_i$. It is true that infinity factors somewhere into the definition, but there is nothing implicit about that. Then we move on to prove something about this set, namely that it is the empty set. The fact that the result in the infinite case often looks somewhat like the result from the finite case is in some sense "magic", but really what happens is that our definitions for the infinite case look like our definitions for the finite case.